# Conda / Anaconda will not update ANY PACKAGE due to environment inconsistency

Tags: linux, conda

I am trying to update/install several packages in conda (I've also tried in Anaconda navigator, it goes nowhere and provides no helpful status information). I keep getting the error:

```
The environment is inconsistent, please check the package plan carefully
The following packages are causing the inconsistency:

  - defaults/linux-64::blaze==0.11.3=py37_0
  - defaults/linux-64::numba==0.41.0=py37h962f231_0
  - defaults/linux-64::pytables==3.4.4=py37ha205bf6_0
  - defaults/linux-64::anaconda==2018.12=py37_0
```

I have read a lot of very similar issues here and on other forums, and tried the following:

`$ conda update <package>` for the packages listed, individually and as a group

`$ conda install <package>` for same

`$ conda update --all`

`$ conda update python`

`$ conda install python`

`$ conda update conda`

`$ conda install conda`

That covers all the suggestions that I have seen in forums, and understood. In every case, I get the error above, followed, after a minute or two by:

```
failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: / 
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
```

This is followed by a several hours long attempt to resolve the environment, which then fails.

OS: Ubuntu 18.04

conda: 4.8.4

python: 3.7.8

Does anyone have any ideas beyond what I've tried?

Comment: Make a new environment.

Comment: Making new environment does not necessarily solve the problem. Better to try re-install of anaconda itself.

Answer (score 2):

I was the same issue after a recent update to my environment.

I used `conda list --revision` to check the last version before this happened and then `conda install --revision <rev num>` to rollback to the latest working version of my environment and that worked for me.